# ¿En dónde está el error cuando quiero hacer el Post?

Tags: html, c#

quería saber si estoy llamando mal a mi método  `[HttpPost]` desde mi html, es un formulario normal, mandándole los datos con el name en las etiquetas.
No llego a ver donde está el error, me darían una mano?

HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper bg-red p-t-180 p-b-100 font-robo">
       <div class="wrapper wrapper--w960">
           <div class="card card-2">
               <div class="card-heading"></div>
               <div class="card-body">
                   <h2 class="title">Envio de Facturas</h2>
                   <form action="~/Home/ConexionWS" method="post">
                       <div class="input-group">
                           <input class="input--style-2" type="number" placeholder="DNI/CUIT" name="cuit" id="cuit" required>
                       </div>
                       <div class="input-group">
                           <input class="input--style-2" type="text" placeholder="Numero de Pedido" name="pedidocliente" id="pedidocliente" required>
                       </div>
                       <div class="input-group">
                           <input class="input--style-2" type="email" placeholder="email" name="dirmail" id="dirmail" required>
                       </div>
                       <div class="input-group">
                           <input  style="width:auto" class="input--style-2" type="text" placeholder="Deseo recibir novedades" contenteditable="false" name="res_code"/>
                           <input  style="width:auto" class="input--style-2" type="checkbox" checked name="acepta" id="checkbox"/>
                       </div>                      
                       <div class="p-t-30">
                           <button class="btn btn--radius btn--green" type="submit" id="enviarFactura">¡Enviar Factura!</button>
                       </div>
                   </form>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
private IActionResult ConexionWS(string cuit, string pedidocliente, string dirmail, string acepta)
```

Lo que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El action del form es una URL relativa o absoluta. Hasta donde sé, darle comodines unix no sale bien

Comment: Agregue el código completo del controlador

Comment: Porque el código completo del controlador?

Answer (score 1):

Listo, el problema es que estaba llamando al metodo HttpPost y éste estaba en private

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ConexionWS(string cuit, string pedidocliente, string dirmail, string acepta)
```